# What is the differect between word-wrap and overflow-wrap?

Tags: css, properties

Can someone please help me to figure out the different between those two css properties. I thinks its seem to be same. Please help me out. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes both are same. You may follow this article about this topic.
[Dealing with long words in css](https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/)